# Configure SQL connection string to either connect through internal network or through remote connection

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have an internal MS SQL server, let's say on IP 192.168.1.1 . The clients connect to this server (using my WPF .NET Framework desktop application) using the internal IP address when they are connected to the same network.

Now I want these clients to be able, without the need that they have to change anything, to connect tto that SQL server through the internet (to the server's IP address 12.23.34.45:9876) when they are traveling.

I have added a failover server with the external IP address, but that is not working (the connection just fails because it cannot reach the server, which probably is because it is still trying to connect to the internal IP address).
Probably this failover thing is not meant to be used for my case, but what other solution does exist then?

Comment: Maybe you can try pinging 192.168.1.1 in order to determine if you are connected to the internal Network or not.

Comment: I suggest you have clients connect over a VPN instead of exposing the database server to the public internet.